# Google Colab incompatibility with TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, save, google-colaboratory, tensorboard

In a Google Colab notebook once I execute the commands:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir <data_directory>
```

I am unable to save the model in the cloud, not only automatically but also manually.

Does someone have an idea of why this can be happening?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by not being able to save in the cloud. You can save the model in the current session using `ModelCheckpoints` and then send the output file after training to the could.

Comment: Provide us your code, please, how do you write your logs and are log-files created. Besides, except for `ModelCheckpoints` you can also do it as you said "manually", e.g.: create a `writer = SummaryWriter(log_dir)` and write to it at every needed step `writer.add_scalar('my_val', scalar_value=my_val, global_step=my_step)`

Comment: @ans Thanks both for replying. Only by providing the two code lines that I mentioned in the question, once the TensorBoard module is loaded to the virtual machine in Google Colab, it will not save the file anymore, however, it allows me to edit the file and run it but not save it which is what really I do not understand. I think it is either a bug or I might be having problems with permissions or something similar. I will take a look to the ModelCheckpoints and see if it works, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If its helpful for someone else; executing in an independent module at the beginning the command:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
```

And at the end of the program in a separated module

```
%tensorboard --logdir <folder_name>
```

Worked for me and allows to save my work despite the TensorBoard module being loaded in the system